# Two javascript functions which work independently, but not together?

Tags: javascript, html

Background

I am attempting to write an exercise for Khan Academy. Their code is all available here: https://github.com/Khan/khan-exercises.  This is my first time really programming anything, and I am learning html and js as I go basically just by looking at example code.

As part of this exercise I need to draw a "random function", and find it's zeros.  I have written a zero finding algorithm (Cutting an interval in half repeatedly to zoom in on the zero.).  I know some variant of newton's method is probably faster, but I wanted to insure convergence.  My "random function" takes a set of points values and interpolates those points with a polynomial spline. Each of these work independently: I can graph my "random function" and I can use my zero finding algorithm to, say, approximate the square root of 2 (zero of x^2 - 2 on interval (1,2)).  When I try to find zeros of my "random function" I run into trouble:  My browser goes into an infinite loop or something. I can't even see what the errors are in the developer tools.

So my questions are basically:

1. What mistake have I made which is using up so much computing power here?
2. How could the functions work independently but not together?
3. How can I fix my code?

Since I am working within the whole knhan academy framework, there is too much going into my program to post all the relevant code (it uses Raphael to handle images, has prewritten code to make the exercises all have the same style, etc).  I can give you the html code I have written and the .js file of functions that I have written.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-require="math graphie graphie-helpers steveMath8">
  <head>
      <title>Piecewise-defined function</title>
      <script src="../khan-exercise.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="exercise">
          <div class="vars">


  <var id = "n">randRange(2,4)</var>
  <var id = "abscissas">makeXList()</var>
  <var id = "ordinates">makeYList(-8,8,abscissas.length)</var>
  <var id = "points">makeCoordinates(abscissas,ordinates)</var>
 <var id = "f">(function(x){return niceFunction(x,points)})</var>
 <!-- <var id = "f">(function(x){return x*x-n})</var>-->
 <var id = zeros>locateZeros(f,abscissas)</var>





          </div>

          <div class="problems">
              <div id="problem-type-or-description">
                  <p class="problem">You are going to have to answer 5</p>
                  <p class="question">Answer 5</p>
                  <div class="graphie" id="grid">
                graphInit({
                    range: 10,
                    scale: 20,
                    tickStep: 1,
                    axisArrows: "<->"
                });

            a =style({
                        stroke: "red",
                         strokeWidth: 2
                    }, function() {
                        plot( function( x ) { return niceFunction(x,points);
                        }, [ -10, 10 ] );
                    });;
            a.plot();
            </div>

                  <p class="solution">5</p>
              </div>



          </div>

          <div class="hints">
              <!-- Any hints to show to the student. -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

```
$.extend(KhanUtil, {

//takes num and returns +1 if num>0 or -1 if num<0
steveSign: function(num){
    return num && num/Math.abs(num)
},

// Approximates a root of f on the interval (xmin,xmax) by successively halving the   interval.
steveRoot: function(f,xmin,xmax){
    var l = xmin
    var r = xmax
    var z = 0
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        z = (l + r)/2
        if (KhanUtil.steveSign(f(l)) == KhanUtil.steveSign(f(z))){ l = z}
        else{r = z}   

    }
    return z
},

//takes a function and a list of abscissas, and returns an array of zeros - one zero between each pair of abscissas that are of
//opposite sign
locateZeros: function(f,abscissas){
    var len = abscissas.length
    var list = []
    var z = 0

    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++){
       var x0 = abscissas[i]
       var x1 = abscissas[i+1]
       var y0 = f(x0)
       var y1 = f(y0)

       if (KhanUtil.steveSign(y0) !== KhanUtil.steveSign(y1)){
           z = KhanUtil.steveRoot(f,x0,x1)
           list.push(KhanUtil.steveSign(f(x0)))
       }

    }
    return list
},

    steveCubic: function(x){return -Math.pow(x,3)/2+3*x/2},

//niceFunction is a C^1 function which connects the points in "points".  It is designed to be used 
//in my "curveSketchingIntuition" exercise.  Every point in the "points" will have 0 slope, except the first and last point.
niceFunction: function(x,points){

    len = points.length

    var x1 = points[0][0]
    var x2 = points[1][0]
    var y1 = points[0][1]
    var y2 = points[1][1]
    var k = (y1 - y2)/Math.pow(x1-x2,2)

    if (x<x2){return k*Math.pow(x-x2,2)+y2}

    for (i=1;i<len-2;i++){
        var x1 = points[i][0]
        var x2 = points[i+1][0]
        var y1 = points[i][1]
        var y2 = points[i+1][1]

        xNew = (x-x1)*2/(x2-x1)-1
        yNew = (KhanUtil.steveCubic(xNew)+1)*(y2-y1)/2+y1
        if (x>=x1 && x<x2){return yNew}

        }


    var x1 = points[len-2][0]
    var x2 = points[len-1][0]
    var y1 = points[len-2][1]
    var y2 = points[len-1][1]
    var k = (y2 - y1)/Math.pow(x1-x2,2)
    if (x>=x1){return k*Math.pow(x-x1,2)+y1}

},

makeXList: function(){
array = [-10]
i=0
while(array[i]<10){
    x = array[i]+3*KhanUtil.randRange(1,3)
    if (x<10){array.push(x)}
    i=i+1
    }
array.push(10)
return array

},

makeYList:function(min,max,n){
    excluded = [0]
    array = [KhanUtil.randRangeExclude(min,max,excluded)]
    excluded.push(array[0])
    array.push[KhanUtil.randRangeExclude(min,max,excluded)]
    excluded = [0]
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
        if (array[i-2]<array[i-1]){
            array.push(KhanUtil.randRangeExclude(min,array[i-1]-1,excluded))
            }
        else{array.push(KhanUtil.randRangeExclude(array[i-1]+1,max,excluded))}
        }

    return array

},

    makeCoordinates:  function(array1,array2){
    array = []
    for (i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
        array.push([array1[i],array2[i]])
    }
    return array
},
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it is an infinite loop (do you see CPU usage maxed)?

Comment: Yup, CPU usage max out on safari

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to think through this problem so throughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my code.  The problem seems to be that in both functions I had a for loop that looked like this

```
for(i=0;i=10;i++)
```

I changed that to

```
for(var i=0;i=10;i++)
```

apparently my program was treating i as a global variable, and so my two interacting functions were both incrementing the same i.  Does this make sense?  it seems like a pretty lousy feature to have in a programming language.  Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I will accept this answer in a couple days unless someone comes along and spells out exactly how this happened and why, in which case I will accept that person's answer.

Comment: It seems this explains it:  http://scribu.net/blog/javascript-var-keyword-for-php-developers.html

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that! JavaScript can definitely do some pretty nasty things if you aren't careful. Glad you found out what was wrong though.

Comment: well, agreed with @Micheal, its closure in java script that one must always keep into account ... but ... as per my weak knowledge wouldn't any programming language behave like this ?... if you haven't declared 'i' in the for statement it would tend to look at a global level .... if not found would return a compile time error but java script on the other hand would just go on and declare it ....

Comment: Aukhan, in most programming languages (in my very limited experience) variables defined within the scope of another function are not global unless you explicitly declare them to be.  They are usually local to the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your while loop here:

```
makeXList: function(){
array = [-10]
i=0
while(array[i]<10){
    x = array[i]+3*KhanUtil.randRange(1,3)
    if (x<10){array.push(x)}
    i=i+1
    }
array.push(10)
return array

},
```

Note that you are always incrementing `i`, but not always pushing a new value onto the array. If `x` is larger than 10, you will increment `i`, but there will be no element there, and that is probably what's causing your infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try to modify this and see if it fixes things.  It is strange that I am able to graph niceFunction at all if this is the problem though.  Maybe it is just generating values of the array as it needs them?

Comment: I actually commented out that whole code block and just manually input an array of abscissas, and I am facing the same problem.  So this was not the error (or maybe I should say, it is only one of the errors!)

Comment: You're right, I just checked and when comparing against undefined the statement will evaluate to false.

Comment: Michael: in case it was still bugging you, I have figured it out and posted an answer.  Thanks for all the help.